# The dollar sign in Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a small program with the purpose of findings website URLs ( it is the simplest you could possibly imagine though ). Here's how a relevant portion of it looks like :

```
webURLregex = re.compile(r'''(
   (https://|http://)
   ([a-zA-Z0-9.%+\\/_-]+)
   ([a-zA-Z0-9%+\\/_-]$)
   )''',re.VERBOSE)
```

Despite the ''findall'' method I used to search the pasted string, the program gives me only one result, despite the copied text consisting of over 5 URLs.
When I delete the dollar sign, it works properly.

I do understand that the dollar sign is unnecessary because the aim of the line it is placed within is only to not match the pasted string's last character if it happens to be a comma or a dot, but I thought the dollar sign could not change the output at all, and apparently it did.

Out of six results I got by running the without-dollar-sign program, only one remains ( for an unknown reasons considering they all look the same schematically ) when I add the dollar sign. I tried adding it right after the closing bracket of the parentheses as well, and the output is one string as well.

Any idea about how and why this occurs would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `$` binds the expression to the end of a line / the string, meaning you'll only find urls that terminates the string. `$` is a metacharacter in the world of regex. If you are looking for `$` literally, use `\$`.

Comment: My goal is to integrate any one of these characters within square brackets to the end of the regular expresson though. I still don't clearly understand why it only matches one string ?

Comment: Without seeing the input it is hard to specify precisely. But it can only find one url because it can only find the url that terminates the string (thanks to the $). Only one url can be at the end of the string. e.g. in the string "http://www.a.com http://www.b.com" only http://www.b.com is matched because it is the only url that terminates the string.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use \$ instead of $.

```
webURLregex = re.compile(r'''(
   (https://|http://)
   ([a-zA-Z0-9.%+\\/_-]+)
   ([a-zA-Z0-9%+\\/_-]\$)
   )''',re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: I don't, I wanted the given line to be presented in the end of the returned string ( which it would either way so the dollar sign would be unnecessary, but I still wanted to try it out and got an unexpected result).